# Deleting Chinese Characters from a MS Word file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, docx, file-writing

I'm trying to use python to make a script to delete Chinese characters from a MS word document, the only problem is that the file was originally a Chinese word document so the formatting is just a bunch of text boxes. Right now I have my code able to read through all of the text boxes but for some reason when I try to 
replace the characters nothing happens. I'm new to python so if anyone could help me understand my code better then I would be appreciative.

```
our_dic = ['≤', '≥', '~', '%', '\n', '\t', '℃']
for x in range(10): 
    our_dic.append(str(x))

temp = set()
trns = None

for x in file_array:
    doc = Document(x)
    rep_dic = {}
    for table in doc.tables:
        print("loading...")
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    for letters in paragraph.text:
                        if (ord(letters) < 128) or (letters in our_dic) :
                            temp.add(letters)
                    for k in temp:
                        print(paragraph.text.replace(k, ""))
doc.save(x)
print("I finished your deletion")
```

Right now I'm using print to test the code but the replace doesn't seem to print code without the Chinese characters in it.

Comment: What's left in the MS word document after deleting all the Chinese characters?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I worked on my code a bit and found that text boxes weren't being accessed by the above code. I'm just confused on how to access all text boxes of a word doc. Other than that the code deletes all other instances of chinese

Answer (score -1):

Why the heck are you using Python for this, and not VBA, which is already built right into Word?!  You should try something like this:

```
Sub DeleteAllObjects()
For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1  
    ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Delete  
Next i
End Sub
```

Or, search for the specific 'formatting' that represents all Chinese characters, and replace with blanks.

See this for more info.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/748-word-remove-all-text-boxes.html